# Providex Query Performance

Tags: sql, database

I am running a query against a providex database that we use in MAS 90. The query has three tables joined together, and has been slow but not unbearably, taking about 8 minutes per run. The query has a fair number of conditions in the where clause:

I'm going to omit the select part of the query as its long and simple, just a list of fields from the three tables that are to be used in the results.

But the tables and the where clauses in the 8 minute run time version are:

(The first parameter is the lower bound of the user-selected date range, the second is the upper bound.)

```
FROM  "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail" "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail", 
"AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader" "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader", "IM1_InventoryMasterfile" 
"IM1_InventoryMasterfile" 
WHERE "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail"."InvoiceNo" = "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."InvoiceNo" 
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail"."ItemCode" = "IM1_InventoryMasterfile"."ItemNumber" 
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."SalespersonNo" = 'SMC' 
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."OrderDate" >= @p_dr 
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."OrderDate" <= @p_d2
```

However, it turns out that another date field in the same table needs to be the one that the Date Range is compared with. So I changed the Order Dates at the end of the WHERE clause to InvoiceDate. I haven't had the query run successfully at all yet. And I've waited over 40 minutes. I have no control over indexing because this is a MAS 90 database which I don't believe I can directly change the database characteristics of.

What could cause such a large (at least 5 fold) difference in performance. Is it that OrderDate might have been indexed while InvoiceDate was not? I have tried BETWEEN clauses but it doesn't seem to work in the providex dialect. I am using the ODBC interface through .NET in my custom report engine. I have been debugging the report and it is running at the database execution point when I asked VS to Break All, at the same spot where the 8 minute report was waiting, so it is almost certainly either something in my query or something in the database that is screwed up.

If its just the case that InvoiceDates aren't indexed, what else can I do in the providex dialect of SQL to optimize the performance of these queries? Should I change the order of my criteria? This report gets results for a specific salesperson which is why the SMC clause exists. The prior clauses are for the inner joins, and the last clause is for the date range.

I used an identical date range in both the OrderDate and InvoiceDate versions and have ran them all mulitiple times and got the same results.

Comment: Good luck! Maybe I'm just ill-informed but I've not heard of ProvideX. With such a specific question about a not-too-widely adopted database, you may be better off finding the forums provided by the vendor.  Maybe I'm wrong and there's hundreds of SO users who can help. I kinda doubt it.

Comment: Indexes MIGHT be the issue, but only if you have a fairly large DB or massively underpowered server. Could it be that the invoice date column is computed rather than a value column? Can you look at the task manager/Perfmon on the server to see if it's idle, thrashing disk, or burning CPU?

Comment: Sage Software's MAS 90/200 accounting software uses providex, in addition to having a SQL Server edition.

I will check. Never thought about testing resource consumption. This is a mid-size business accounting system, so there are a significant but not huge number of records in the tables affected

Comment: I have put a call out to one of our consultants who works with Sage/Providex a lot, so if he has an answer tommorrow, I will share it here. We have had problems with query performance for a while in providex, so it may be that the db platform isn't that good after all.

Comment: I think, there is a need for `ProvideX` tag. I tried to add that, but could not add due to less reputation. It will be nice, if somebody with reputation 1500+ can add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know exactly why it was so slow, but we had another problem with the results coming from the query (we switched back to using OrderDate). We weren't getting some of the results because of the nature of the IM1 table.

So I added a Left Outer Join once I figured out Providex's syntax for that. And for some reason, even though we still have 3 tables, it runs a lot faster now.

The new query criteria are:

```
FROM  "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader" "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader", 
{OJ "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail" "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "IM1_InventoryMasterfile" "IM1_InventoryMasterfile"
ON "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail"."ItemCode" = 
"IM1_InventoryMasterfile"."ItemNumber" }
WHERE "AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail"."InvoiceNo" = 
"AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."InvoiceNo" AND 
"AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."SalespersonNo" = 'SMC' 
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."InvoiceDate" >= ? 
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."InvoiceDate" <= ?
```

Strange, but at least I learned more of the world of Providex Sql in the process.

Comment: Where did you find the syntax for your JOIN statement(s)?  I'm trying to JOIN a header file to a detail file just as you are but I am not having any luck.

Comment: I have a providex reference manual I can find next time I’m at work. The syntax is definitely weird.

Comment: You have to use double quotes for field names, not [ ]. But I also found this.

inneroj tableref INNER JOIN tableref ON boolean |
tableref INNER JOIN inneroj ON boolean
oj tableref LEFT OUTER JOIN tableref ON boolean |
tableref LEFT OUTER JOIN oj ON boolean | inneroj

Answer (score 0):

I've never used providex before.

A search turned up [this reference article](http://www.pvx.com/support/docs/reference/PVXLanguage0029.htm) on the syntax for creating an index.

Looking over your query, there's three tables and five criteria.  Two of the criteria are "join criteria", and three criteria are filtering criteria:

```
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."SalespersonNo" = 'SMC'
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."OrderDate" >= @p_dr
AND "AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader"."OrderDate" <= @p_d2
```

I don't know how good SalespersonNo is for limiting return results, but it might be good to add an index on that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the power to add indexes to MAS 90 systems. However, the problem has gone away, thought it is still a mystery why it was so slow in the first place.

Comment: It seems they have taken down the article mentioned by David B.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used .NET so my question may show ignorance, but in Access you must use a SQL Pass-Through query to wring any results from ProvideX, if more than one table is involved.